# Firefox is already running but not responding. - driver issue with multiprocessing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, python-multiprocessing

The problem occurs only when I want to use firefox profile, and only when i want to use it alongside multiprocessing. I wanted my script to create few webdriver instances at once, and scrape  the urls concurrently to save some time. Unfortunately there seems to be a problem with using a firefox profile at the same time by more than one instance.

I have tried to copy the profile folder, but strangely it is not recognized at all (I have tried to create a  copy in the same folder as the original too). The copied folder, no matter where it is, is just being omitted when the script runs, even when I tried to copy more than just a profile folder itself.

When i use the original folder (only from the Roaming, from Localis the same as it is with a copied folder), the website is loding, but the popup keeps opening: Firefox is already running, but it is not responding...

Here's my driver setup:

```
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    #options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
    options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36")
    #options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
    options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    options.add_argument('--disable-features=AutomaticRedirectBlocking')
    options.add_argument("--profile=C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\xxxxx.Moz-user")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
```